# For Loop to only run on 5th iteration

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I'm trying to write an inline for loop that would run on the 5th iteration 
and onward of the output of a command.

So skip the first 5 and execute on any iteration higher than 5.

```
20191017t161323 --- skipped
20191018t074509 --- skipped
20191018t094457 --- skipped
20191018t103440 --- skipped
20191018t123800 --- skipped
20191018t132445 --- gcloud app versions delete "20191018t132445" --service="SERVICE_NAME" --format="value(VERSION)"
20191018t155251 --- gcloud app versions delete "20191018t155251" --service="SERVICE_NAME" --format="value(VERSION)"
20191021t070429 ...
20191021t075342 ...
...


for i in $(gcloud app versions list --service="SERVICE_NAME" --filter="SERVING_STATUS=STOPPED" --format="value(VERSION)"); do gcloud app versions delete "$i" --service="SERVICE_NAME" --format="value(VERSION)" --quiet; done
```

**Breakdown**

```
gcloud app versions list --service="SERVICE_NAME" --filter="SERVING_STATUS=STOPPED" --format="value(VERSION)"
```

will return a list of IDs that will be passed into

```
gcloud app versions delete "$i" --service="SERVICE_NAME" --format="value(VERSION)" --quiet
```

I'd like to have this run inline without any file dependencies. Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean with *file dependencies*?

Comment: not sure I understand the comment ... `run on the 5th iteration of the output of the command` ... ???  do you mean that you only want to process the 5th 'line' of output from the command? are you running the command 5 times and only want to process the output from the 5th run? how about providing an example of the output from the command (eg, first 10 lines of output) and some comments about what you want to do with each line of output?

Comment: my mistake. I want the command in the body to run on any iteration higher than 5 skipping the first five.

Answer (score 1):

Discard the first five lines with `tail -n +6`.

```
gcloud app versions list --service="SERVICE_NAME" --filter="SERVING_STATUS=STOPPED" --format="value(VERSION)" \
    | tail -n +6 \
    | xargs -I{} gcloud app versions delete {} --service="SERVICE_NAME" --format="value(VERSION)" --quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out:

```
for i in $(gcloud app versions list --service="angular-dev" --filter="SERVING_STATUS=SERVING" --format="value(VERSION)" | sed -n "6,$p"); do gcloud app versions stop "$i" --service="angular-dev" --format="value(VERSION)"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i=1
for item in list ...; do
  if [ i -ge 5 ] ; then
     : actions to take for fifth item and later
  fi
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```